# JQuery UI draggable destroy, then draggable again not works

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I use the jquery ui draggable, droppable plugins. I wrote this code:

```js
$(".droppable").draggable({
  containment:"window",
  appendTo:$("#canvas"),
  helper:"clone",
  scroll:false
});

$("#canvas").droppable({
  accept:".droppable",
  drop:function(event,ui){
    ui.draggable.draggable("destroy");
    ui.draggable.draggable({
      containment:"window",
      appendTo:$("#canvas"),
      helper:"clone",
      scroll:false
    });
  }
});
```

but it doesn't work, the draggable object is not draggable anymore after I dropped it on the dropzone.
If I write this in jsfiddle (http://fiddle.jshell.net/te4sjtcz/), everything is OK, the draggable object is still draggable after the draggable("destroy").

If I use console.log(ui.draggable.draggable("instance")), it produces:

- Before destroy: `<div.... etc.`
- After destroy: undefined
- After reattach draggable: `<div.... etc`

Other info is that if I use ui.draggable.draggable("option","key","value") format for setup, everything is fine again. Why I can't use the simple .draggable({}) format in my code and why does it work in jsfiddle? (I use the same library)

Update 1: I see that the destory removes these classes: ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle, and after reattach I don't see them.

Update 2: If I put the reattach block into a setTimeout(HERE,0), it works. But it's not a good workaround... because I don't know why it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with jquery-ui 1.9.2 (your jsFiddle project) and doesn't work with jquery-ui 1.11.3 version (your code snippet project).
The difference is in the draggable destroy method. Starting with 1.11.0 version [the _destroy function just sets the destroyOnClear flag to true and returns](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/draggable.js#L92), so the actual "destroy" occurs after exiting the droppable drop function.

So if it is absolutely necessary to create the same draggable in the drop function again setTimeout will be useful.